# Ubuntu Server Bionic Beaver non-graphical change resolution

Tags: grub2, 18.04

I'm trying to change the resolution of my ubuntu server. sadly all tutorials seem to be doing it by using xrandr which tells me "can't open display" since i'm using the non-graphical version.

I also tried editing the /etc/default/grub file by adding

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1152x864x32
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

followed by sudo update-grub
Sadly this does nothing to change my resolution. :<

Comment: did you reboot after the update? you have a monitor connected to your server or are sshing in?

Answer (score 0):

**Modify / add the following lines to `/etc/default/grub` to match the ones below**

> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="video=<your_video_mode> gfxpayload=true"
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=<your_video_mode> gfxpayload=true"
> ...
> # The resolution used on graphical terminal
> # note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
> # you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
> GRUB_GFXMODE=<resolution_needed>
> GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD=<resolution_needed>
> GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=<resolution_needed>
> ```

**Run update-grub**

```
sudo update-grub
```

**Reboot**

```
sudo reboot
```

You can find more information [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091375/ubuntu-18-server-console-resolution-problem).