# Ubuntu 18 server console resolution problem

Tags: server, 18.04, display-resolution, console, 18.10

I don't use desktop, so no X-window is involved.

How do I change resolution of text console?

Things I tried:

- Setting in GRUB: by either video=, or GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX, it works - GRUB is displayed in correct resolution, up to 3440x1440, **but a second before login prompt appears, it snaps back to 800x600.** GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep doesn't work.
- fbset - it doesn't work at all, in Virtualbox I get: "ioctl fbioput_vscreeninfo invalid argument" error, or in case of hardware (Intel BMC - basically Matrox G200, Quadro K2000, K4000, Radeon X550, HD3450, GeForce FX5200 and 760Ti) it is just ignored, like literally nothing happens. Resolution definitions are correct, as far as I can eyeball it in dbfile.
- nomodeset makes no difference
- All my systems are using UEFI.
- This applies to both analog (VGA) displays and those using digital connections.
- This applies to Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 LTS and 18.10.

It's rather uncomfortable at 800x600 - any other ideas?

Comment: After changing the settings did you run `sudo update-grub`? If not those settings are valid for that session only.

Comment: Yes, I did. Like I wrote, I can freely control resolution at which GRUB is displaying its menu, and by extension, resolution at which kernel boots. Just not anything forward.

Comment: And did you set all the five options suggested in the deleted answer, before running the update-grub command? (I think you may ask "terdon" to undelete the answer for you.)

Comment: Or I can just add the five lines in question :)
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="video=<your_video_mode> gfxpayload=true";
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=<your_video_mode> gfxpayload=true">;
GRUB_GFXMODE=<resolution_needed>;
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD=<resolution_needed>;
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=<resolution_needed>;